# Does windows ‘reset this pc’ format the drive?

Tags: windows, formatting, reset

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I tried to find this online but can’t see any answers.

When you use windows ‘reset this pc’ does it format the drive, and does it differ if you select the ‘clean the drive’ option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How to Reset Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html) :

> **Just remove my files** = This performs a quick format, and doesn't take long. Your files might be recoverable by someone else since they
> are only marked as deleted. You would use this option if you are
> keeping your PC.
>
> **Fully clean the drive** = This performs a secure erase to fully clean your drive by overwriting your files so that they can't be
> easily recovered. This can take several hours to finish. You would
> want to do this option if you are recycling or selling your computer.

Both options do a format, but only the second option really erases the
data. Note that on an internal SSD, there's a good chance the a
quick format will TRIM the entire disk.

From [Does a windows 10 quick format still send a TRIM command on SSD?](https://superuser.com/questions/1649731/does-a-windows-10-quick-format-still-send-a-trim-command-on-ssd)

> Answer: Quick format does not do TRIM on external USB but does do it on internal SATA disks.